# Regular expression to extract number before parenthesis

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have a string like below..  I just want to extract the all numbers before the `(` till the character starts.

`12XYXXX12345(XXYYZZ)`

XXYY are just placeholders for characters..

I can extract the data before the open parenthesis `(` using below expression. But I dont know how to extract the numbers alone.

```
^[^\(]*
```

Comment: Well, right now, even [`\d(?=\w*\()`](https://regex101.com/r/nuYATm/1) will work for you. Could you please provide what regex flavor you are using?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Are XYXXX placeholders for more digits? If not, do you want 12, 12345, or 1212345 extracted? Also, are there always 2 numbers divided by one letter-only word, or can it be `1x2xy3whatever(...`?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I just want 12345.. XYXXX are all characters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code extracted all the numbers.. I just want the numbers between character and (

Comment: Then extract all numbers immediately before a bracket. That seems not too difficult. Like `sed 's/\([0-9]\))/\1/g'`   or so

Comment: @PadmanabhanVijay: Yes, but you did not define the regex flavor. And your string has no digits anywhere else.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry My bad. I am using Regex in Hive Query.  I am pretty new to regex. thats y my queries are bit confusing.  Whatever works in python will work in hive. So flavor should be Python. Aplogize if am wrong

Comment: I think Hive uses Java regex. Try [`\\G\\w*?(\\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/nuYATm/2) and grab Group 1 values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry! It didnt work.. It just gives the first digit.

Comment: It will work if you use the code to get *multiple* matches. Your question is now off-topic.

Comment: Reading your question again: You say that `^[^\(]*` almost works, but you want just the number. Well then, express that: `[0-9]*(`. You can simply omit the anchor `^`. You can also demand that there is a non-digit to the left: `[^0-9][0-9]*(`. The resulting string will have one extraneous character (a non-digit) before the actual number, and the bracket as the last character. It's trivial to remove those with string operations, but alternatively you can define a group which contains just the number by bracketing that (with escaped brackets): `[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)(` and retrieve that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hive> select regexp_extract ('12XYXXX12345(XXYYZZ)','\\d+(?=\\()',0);
OK
12345
```

OR

```
hive> select regexp_extract ('12XYXXX12345(XXYYZZ)','(\\d+)\\(',1);
OK
12345
```

Comment: Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = "12XYXXX12345(XXYYZZ)";
console.log(x.match(/^[^\(]*/)[0].match(/\d/g).join(""));
```

The code first gets `12XYXXX12345` and then performs a regex to match digits and then combines all matches.

Comment: I am using regex in my hive query So match conditions wont work.. is there a way we can nest the regex queries. ?